# React-Bootstrap CSS issue

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

When I import Bootstrap CSS it adds extra CSS to the navbar. As it is shown in the image below. I am using bootstrap cards in this code but not for Navbar. When I remove the Bootstrap CSS It works fine.

[image]

You can check the code [here](https://github.com/Bhavik-Jain/Portfolio)

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: It adds extra css because bootstrap has their own css for the class name that you are using. So you could use different class names.

Comment: I add different class names in Navbar but it doesn't work.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing by adding  Bootstrap CSS?

Comment: You can check the image. When I import bootstrap it puts underlines in the navigation item and even change font size and style.

Answer (score 2):

if your problem is the under line you can omit that using

```
style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}
```

here is your modified `navbar.jsx` file

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

function Navbar(){
    return(
        <>
            <header className="l-header"> 
                <div className="navi bd-grid">
                    <div>
                        <NavLink to="#" className="navi__logo">Portfolio</NavLink>
                    </div>

                    <div className="navi__menu" id="navi-menu">
                        <ul className="navi__list">
                            <li className="navi__item">
                                <NavLink to="#home" className="navi__link menu" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>Home</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="navi__item">
                                <NavLink to="#about" className="navi__link" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>About</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="navi__item">
                                <NavLink to="#skills" className="navi__link" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>Skills</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="navi__item">
                                <NavLink to="#work" className="navi__link" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>Work</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="navi__item">
                                <NavLink to="#contact" className="navi__link" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>Contact</NavLink>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div className="navi__toggle" id="navi-toggle">
                        <i className='bx bx-menu'></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </>
    );
};

export default Navbar;
```

output will be something like this
[image]

Comment: Yes It removes the underline but navigation stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import the bootstrap on your index.js file and it should solve the problem.